# Firebase onSnapShot() doesn't rerender

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a multiplayer game using Firebase and react.
This is what I currently got:

A player can enter his name and creates a lobby document inside a "GameLobbies"-collection.

The page he enters contains a newly generated code, which he can share with friends. It also contains a list of players inside the lobby.

**This is what player 1 sees after entering the lobby** (also firebase):
[first player entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGXI6.png)

As you can see everything works as intended

If I now add a new player via firebase, something strange happens: A rerender causes, but it doesn't add the second player in my ul tag

**This is what player 1 sees when player 2 enters:** [second player entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc3lJ.png)

Strange, but it gets stranger when player 3 (and every player after) joins.
Every player that joins after player 2 don't cause a rerender.

**This is what player 1 sees when player 3 enters:** [third+ player entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9QLJ.png)

Can anyone help me with that? English is not my first language so I hope these pictures help illustrate my problem.

Here's the code to the whole page

```
import Style from './NewLobby.module.css'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { db } from "../services/firestore";
import { v4 } from 'uuid'


const NewLobby = () => {

    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
    const [lobby, setLobby] = useState({});
    const location = useLocation();
    const currentUserId = v4();
    const lobbiesRef = db.collection("GameLobbies");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.state.objective === "createLobby") {
            console.log('create lobby')
            createLobbyInDatabase();
        } else if (location.state.objective === "joinLobby") {
            console.log('join lobby')

            findLobbyByCode();
        }
    }, [])

    const createLobbyInDatabase = () => {
        // getting lobby data
        const code = createLobbyCode();
        const lobbyId = v4();

        // creating lobby in firebase

        lobbiesRef.doc(lobbyId).set({
            code: code,
            id: lobbyId,
        })

        // creating players collection in lobby doc and assign current user
        lobbiesRef.doc(lobbyId).collection("players").doc(currentUserId).set({
            name: location.state.username,
            score: 0,
            id: currentUserId
        })

        // get lobby

        lobbiesRef.doc(lobbyId).get().then(doc => {
            setLobby(doc.data());
        })

        // get real-time lobby players database

        lobbiesRef.doc(lobbyId).collection("players").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            const changes = snapshot.docChanges();
            let playersArr = players;
            changes.forEach(change => {
                if (change.type == 'added') {
                    playersArr.push(change.doc.data());
                }
            })
            console.log(playersArr);
            setPlayers(playersArr);
        })
    }

    const findLobbyByCode = () => {
        // TODO
    }

    const createLobbyCode = () => {
        const codeLength = 4;
        const charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        let codeTemp = '';
        for (let i = 0, n = charset.length; i < codeLength; ++i) {
            codeTemp += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n))
        }
        return codeTemp
    }



    return (
        <section className={Style.section}>
            <p>Code: {lobby.code}</p>
            <p>Players:</p>
            <ul>
                {console.log('render:', players)}
                {players.map(player => {
                    console.log('players.map(player => player.name):', player.name);
                    return <li className={Style.li} key={player.id}>{player.name}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </section>

    );
};

export default NewLobby;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are referring playerArr to player and modifying it and then setting it back using setPlayer(), all the time the its the same player.

you can try something like this

```
const changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        let playersArr = [...players];
        changes.forEach(change => {
            if (change.type == 'added') {
                playersArr.push(change.doc.data());
            }
        })
        console.log(playersArr);
        setPlayers(playersArr);
```

Or you better way is just replace `setPlayers(playerArr)` with `setPlayers([...playerArr])`

This is treated a new array since its the copy and not reference to the array

Comment: When I substitute my code with yours, player 1's name gets replaced by player 2's name. Also, what do you mean with setPlayers([...playerArr])? I get an error saying playerArr is undefined. UPDATE: i think you ment setPlayers([...playerArr]) (playerS). It works now thank you!

Comment: yeah, sorry my bad
it should be setPlayers([...players])

Comment: basic idea is to use copy rather than reference